# QR Code Scanner in Android using ZXING library

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am following this material to implement [QRCode Scanner in Android](http://phpmyweb.net/2012/07/18/integrating-zxing-in-your-android-app-as-standalone-scanner/).

Step by step, after implementing the following code in my application, I am getting error in **GingerbreadOpenCameraInterface.java** class. Following image is the error I am facing with.

[image]

It is showing error as:

```
  1. The method `getNumberOfCameras()` is undefined for the type Camera
  2. `CameraInfo` cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

The following is the **manifest file**:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.demo.qrdemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>


 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".QRDemo"
        android:label="title_activity_qrdemo" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Can anyone help me with the following issue?

Comment: did you kept library files in your libs folder?

Comment: i added only core.jar file in libs folder. Should i have to add any other jar files.?

Comment: you provided a link in that its clear how to Integrate the ZXing library?

Comment: sorry i didnt get you what you are saying..

Comment: http://phpmyweb.net/2012/07/18/integrating-zxing-in-your-android-app-as-standalone-scanner/ in this link its there Integrate the ZXing library.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you use API level >= 9, also make sure that you have imported the correct `Camera` class (there is more than one). You need `android.hardware.Camera`.

EDIT (after you posted some code):

replace this

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

with

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
```

Comment: I imported the following in that class.